# Change MAC address with software in Azure VM

Tags: macos, azure, virtual-machine

If I change MAC address of my Azure VM. Can I live trouble with this action?
Has anyone ever tried something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

@Berk Apologies for the delay in response and all the inconvenience caused because of the issue.

While I see a lot of articles describing in details how you could do it, modifying MAC address is not **officially** supported  in Azure. And, it will incur issues to the VM itself, mostly connectivity and etc., if you change the MAC address. The MAC address is auto assigned by Azure which cannot be changed.

You can refer to [this FQA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq) and [that article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses) to get a better idea about Azure VNet and VM NIC configuration.

Similar feedback was provided previously [there](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/5217933-static-mac-address#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D) and answered by Product group.

If your ask if you will get any troubles legally, I'd say no, unless your actions/tests are causing harm to any other Microsoft customers. Same set of rules as [there](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/pentest-rules-of-engagement).